# How to disable auto-generated unit tests in Grails 2.3.x

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.3

Is there a global setting to disable auto-generation of unit tests in Grails 2.3.x?

I created a controller using `create-controller com.foo.MyController`, and Grails auto-created `com.foo.MyControllerSpec`...while this is nice, I want to prevent it from occurring.

According to [this](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#testing), any `create-*` or `generate-*` action auto-generates unit tests, but the documentation fails to mention how, if at all, this can be disabled.

Comment: You should modify `scaffolding`, cause `create-controller` GANT script is written in that plugin, so you should modify script to change its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create the class manually inside your IDE or editor. A controller class is pretty simple (just a class ending with the convention “Controller” in the `grails-app/controllers` directory)

Comment: Hi @Graeme, I know it's easy to create the class, but we're documenting tutorials for internal Grails framework we designed, and most who will use it have no experience in grails, so using `create-*` makes things easy for n00bs!

Comment: There is no global setting to disable the creation of unit tests, at least not for the scripts provided by the scaffolding plugin.  You could submit a pull request to add such a feature.  I think the default should be to create the tests but an option to disable that is reasonable.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, where should I create the pull request?

Comment: Relevant scripts provided by the scaffolding plugin may be found at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-scaffolding/tree/master/scripts.  Relevant scripts in grails-core may be found at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/master/grails-scripts/src/main/scripts.